# Add translation for Model Translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, rails-i18n

Is it possible to translate "SettingsTranslation" in this pic.

I tried to add different things to my yml files / tried with placing label but no luck so far.

[image]

Comment: I also added: 

in my yml file:
      settings:
        one: "Paramètres"
        other: "Paramètres"
      setting_translation:
        one: "todo"
        other: "todo"

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `config/locales/{locale}.yml` :

```
activerecord:
  models:
    user: "Utilisateur"
```